# Symfony: how to get values from parameters.yml in an AbstractType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I'm trying to get values form an array which I declared in parameters.yml

```
# parameters.yml
parameters:
    ...
    objects: {object1: 1, object2: 2, object3: 3}
```

but once I try to get "objects" from that file using this code

```
$builder->add('list', ChoiceType::class, array ('objects' => $this->container->getParameter('categories') ));
```

I get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined property: Project\Bundle\Form\EntityType::$container
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You have to inject the ContainerInterface inside your Class.

**services.yml**

```
form.my_entity_type:
  class: AppBundle\Form\MyEntityType
  arguments:
    - '@service_container'
  tags:
    - { name: form.type }
```

**MyEntityType**

```
/** @var ContainerInterface */
protected $container;

/**
 * @param ContainerInterface $container
 */
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $params = $this->container->getParameter('my-params');
    ....
```

Comment: Just to add that you have to include (use): use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the `Project\Bundle\Form\EntityType` as [a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-field-service), you will be able to inject the data into it, along with any other services it needs. You will still be able to refer to the type as `EntityType::class` when you include it, as Symfony will recognise that class is defined as a service.

It will make testing it a little more 'interesting' though